# Storing and generating instance of classes using generics

Tags: generics, swift

So I want to create instances that conforms to a specific protocol. I want to create either instances of A or another class that conforms to TestProtocol. I can't run this code in Playground, so I wonder whats wrong? Or even better, how should this be solved?

```
protocol TestProtocol {
    init(value: Int)
}

class A : TestProtocol {

    init() {}
    required init(value: Int) {

    }
}

func generateWithInstances<T : TestProtocol>(item: T, #numberOfInstances: Int) -> [T] {
    var list: [T] = []
    for index in 1...numberOfInstances {
        list.append(T(value: index))
    }
    return list
}

var list: [TestProtocol] = []
let instanceOfA = A()

list.extend(generateWithInstances(instanceOfA, numberOfInstances: 10))
```

**update**

`Array` `extend`s doesn't support polymorphism (both arrays before and after the extends must be of the same type).

```
extension Array {    

    ...

    mutating func extend<S : SequenceType where T == T>(newElements: S)

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in Swift that this code crashes the compiler or playground. (A helpful error message should be provided.)

As you've noted in your update, the reason it's not working is that `generateWithInstances` returns an array of `A`s (`[A]`), and `extend` requires that `A` be identical to `TestProtocol`:

> [image: 'TestProtocol' is not identical to 'A']

`instances` cannot be casted to `[TestProtocol]` since `TestProtocol` is not a subtype of `A`.

However, you can put the objects in one at a time using `append`:

```
for obj in instances {
    list.append(obj)
}
```

You could write an extension for `Array` that doesn't require type equality.